# android package names if you have multiple apps

Tags: java, android

Say you want to put 2 apps on the android market and on the same google play developer account.

Do you need separate package names, similar package names, or completely different package names?

app1 : package com.myapp1.myname
app2 : ???

other possibilities :

app1 : package com.mycompany.app1 
package com.mycompany.myname (for both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just need to be different. There's no specification on how package names need to be defined for different variants of one app.

My preference is for:

```
com.mycompany.appname.paid
```

and

```
com.mycompany.appname.free
```

Answer (score 1):

Package name must be different for different apps. For example

com.mycompany.app1, com.mycompany.app2

Comment: Thats what I suspected. Thank you.